# gedit-latex-plugin not working correctly

Tags: 15.10, gedit, plugins

I've installed the `gedit-latex-plugin` on my machine running 15.10.

When I enable the plugin, it shows the markup colouring in .tex files, but the menu option `New LaTeX Document...` doesn't appear, and neither do the additional menubar buttons, sidebar panels, or the menu options related to LaTeX documents, such as Build, etc.

The installed version of `gedit` is `3.10.4`, plugin version `3.8.0-3build1`.

I have the same plugin installed on a machine running 14.04 LTS, and the plugin works fine. That machine is also running `gedit 3.10.4`, however the plugin version is `3.8.0-1`, which looks correct according to the [Launchpad page,](https://launchpad.net/gedit-latex-plugin/+packages) but conspicuously differs from 15.10.

Note that on both machines, the plugin was installed using `sudo apt-get install gedit-latex-plugin`.

Comment: Did you go into the gedit plugins dialog (Edit --> Preferences --> Plugins) and select the plugin? Just installing the package doesn't do that AFAIK (since it's a "user" selection)

Comment: I did, enabling the plugin showed the markup, but didn't load the rest of the plugin.
I've since discovered this is a [known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gedit-latex-plugin/+bug/1444670). Posted as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found that this is a known bug. [See here.](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gedit-latex-plugin/+bug/1444670)